# Expression based on class of an object in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am trying to write an expression based on the class of an object.

```
case class Fork(left: CodeTree, right: CodeTree, chars: List[Char], weight: Int) extends CodeTree
case class Leaf(char: Char, weight: Int) extends CodeTree

val l1 = new Leaf('A', 1)
val l2 = new Leaf('B', 1)

val f1 = new Fork(l1, l2, List(l1.char, l2.char), l1.weight + l2.weight)
```

I have tried two methods, but those of them have issues.

Method 1:

```
val w: Int = f1 match {

  case Fork(_, _, _, w) => println("I am a fork")
  case Leaf(_, w) => println("I am a Leaf")
}
```

Error received:

```
Error:(15, 8) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
found   : Leaf
required: Fork
case Leaf(_, w) => {w}
```

Method 2:

`if (l1.isInstanceOf[Fork]) println("I am a fork") else println("I am a leaf")`

Warning received:

```
Warning:(10, 20) fruitless type test: a value of type Leaf cannot also be a Fork
if (l1.isInstanceOf[Fork]) println("I am a fork") else println("I am a leaf")
```

Comment: This: `val f1 = new Fork(...)` here `f1` is of type **Fork**, not of type **CodeTree**, thus the compiler warns you that both tests are fruitless, it will never be a **Leaf**, you may `val f1: CodeTree = new Fork(...)` or even better, I remember that assignment, you have to make a method to combine two code trees into one, that would make the boilerplate of joining the chars and weights for you and will always return a **CodeTree**.

Comment: The text in your code for method 1 does not match the text in the error. Try to have a single piece of code that shows the error and is as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is just a warning because the compiler knows that f1 is always fork and is telling you, that you are basically doing `if (true)`
2. Code that would work for you is:

```scala
val f1: CodeTree = new Fork(l1, l2, List(l1.char, l2.char), l1.weight + l2.weight)

val w = f1 match {
   case f: Fork => println("I am a fork")
   case l: Leaf => println("I am a Leaf")
}
```

- I have annotated the f1 to `CodeTree` type
- I have removed the annotation of `w`

then you can modify to whatever:

```scala
val w = f1 match {
   case f: Fork => f.weight 
   case l: Leaf => l.weight
}
```